# Heartbeat removes default gateway

Tags: routing, heartbeat, heartbeat1

I'm setting up 2 mailservers (Postfix) with heartbeat failover & drbd shared maildirs. For some reason, when starting the heartbeat, the default gateway is lost. Any idea how / why this happens and what the solution is?

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# eth0: ip of this node
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.2.3
        gateaway 192.168.2.46
        netmask 255.255.255.0
# eth0:0: ip address which heartbeat is supposed to take over
iface eth0:0 inet static
        address 192.168.2.5
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

`/etc/ha.d/haresources`:

```
mx1 IPaddr::192.168.2.5
mx1 drbddisk::r0 Filesystem::/dev/drbd0::/syncdata::ext3 nfs-kernel-server
```

Failover works fine, but a the default gateway is lost as soon as heartbeat starts it seems (so, also after booting / not yet taking anything over). So far, the only thing I can think of is adding a `route add default gw 192.168.2.46` in `post-up` & `post-down` of `eth0:0`, but that seems rather ugly....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this an actual typo in your config?

```
    gateaway 192.168.2.46
```

Should be

```
    gateway 192.168.2.46
```

Comment: OMFG... Pfft.... I probably moved things around to much with getting it to work I totally missed this... Fixing now, and if this was the problem all along, you have the right to call me an idiot for a full year...

Comment: Don't worry, mistakes like that do happen all the time. That's why it's good to have an extra eye pair looking at the config files :)

Comment: Even after knowing there was an error here, I had to read it twice to find it :)

Comment: @Chris N: I spotted that because the vertical alignment of text was wrong. The words `address`, `network`, `netmask` and `gateway` in `/etc/network/interfaces` all contain seven characters, so the `gateaway` line being unaligned immediately got my attention. :-) Yes I know, I probably have seen that file too many times in my life.

Comment: Yup, extra eyes help a lot ;). Confirmed this was the one & only problem, thanks!

Comment: @Wrikken: Solved? YOU IDIOT! :P

Comment: Hehe ;) A whole year.... ouch.

Comment: @Wrikken: I'm tempted to reserve `iswrikkenstillanidiot.com` and make it return `YES` until 26th of October, 2012.

Comment: Change "gateway" to "stargate" and you get some really neat traffic from a sniffer.